# Fatal error: Out of memory on Dedicated Server running Magento

Tags: php, magento, memory-leaks, dedicated-server

I'm running Magento on a DS with 4 Gb ram with 2 * Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5400 @ 2.70GHz

I have tweaked the php memory-limit from 64M - 1GB but keep getting memory errors in the admin  area example

```
`Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 48496640) (tried to allocate 189475 bytes)
 in  /home/accountname/public_html/shoponline/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 888`
```

So there is something wrong as its only allocated 46M (if i have that right..?)

This line changes...

The site is still in testing so its not getting any heavy traffic so I'm confused to what the issue maybe...

I'm using APC and memcache

Any general ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Where did you change the memory limit? It appears that it's not taking effect.

I'm assuming you edited php.ini.

You could also try adding...

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

to your .htaccess file and see if that works.

Comment: I have set it in php.ini and .htaccess and ion WHM php editor and have checked settings in phpinfo that they take affect...? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After reading some forums I think i have improved the performance by using the RlimitMem feature in the WHM control panel - this calculates the require limit and adds it to the httpd.conf file see below:

After setting this the backend admin area is 80% faster...!

[image: WHM panelscreenshot]